# extracting the column using AWK

Tags: linux, awk

I am trying to extract column using AWK.
Source file is a .CSV file and below is command I am using:

```
 awk -F ',' '{print $1}' abc.csv > test1
```

Data in file abc.csv is like below:

```
xyz@yahoo.com,160,1,2,3
abc@ymail.com,1,2,3,160
```

But data obtained in test1 is like :

```
abc@ymail.comxyz@ymail.com
```

when file is opened in notepad after downloading the file from server.

Comment: Nope, this wont help to notepad, which requires `\r\n` instead of just `\n` as on Unix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notepad doesn't show newlines created on unix. If you want to add them, try

```
awk -F ',' '{print $1"\r"}' abc.csv > test1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a Window tool to read the output you just need to tell awk to use Windows line-endings as the Output Record Separator:

```
awk -v ORS='\r\n' -F',' '{print $1}' file
```