# calculate current line column less previous line column using awk

Tags: awk

my input

```
a 9
b 2
c 5
d 3
e 7
```

desired output (current line column 2 - previous line column 2)

```
a 9
b 2 -7
c 5 3 
d 3 -2
e 7 4
```

explanation

```
a 9
b 2 -7 ( 2-9 = -7 )
c 5 3  ( 5-2 = 3 )
d 3 -2 ( 3-5 = -2 )
e 7 4  ( 7-3 = 4 )
```

I tried this without success

```
awk '{ print $1, $2,$2 - $(NR-1) }' input
```

I want a awk code to generate an additional column contains de calculation of current line less previous line in column 2

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [extracting the column using AWK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361819/extracting-the-column-using-awk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR==1{ print $0 } NR>1{ print $0,$2 - pre } { pre=$2 }' file
a 9
b 2 -7
c 5 3
d 3 -2
e 7 4
```